# how to automated my selenium web scrapper?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I was able to write a script to scrape using selenium, right now I'm trying to automate it so it can work periodically on a server so I don't bother myself by running it from my local, I did a lot of googling but I got no clue of how I can do that, can anyone simplify things for me ..

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a python script on a linux server periodically you can make a cronjob, since you already have a python script which most probably fetches or scrapes data and saves it in a file. You can make a cronjob and set the exact time it has to run, say for instance after every 2 hours you can do it using something like this,

`crontab -e`

this will open a editor in your terminal, at the bottom of the text just write timing and the command to be executed.

`* * * * */path/to/your/code.py`

from this link you can find out how to fill out the stars https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_1

if you need anymore help with using cronjobs take a look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scheduling-python-scripts-on-linux/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply redo your script on [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) and schedule it as a task and choose the frequency that you want the script to be executed. The current frequency options available include; script runs always, hourly or daily.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if it'll really work but

```
while True:
    whole
    code
    here
    time.sleep(period required)
```